# What does !varname do in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have this snippet of bash:

[image]

I'd understand the snippet if the exclamation mark didn't exist, as it's a simple check of whether `varname` is empty.

What the heck is `!varname`?

Comment: In short, "${!varname}" is the value of the variable whose _name_ is `$varname`.

Comment: For future reference, [never post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?cb=1).

Comment: Also, the `sh` tag should be used only for questions about POSIX sh. This question asks about a bash-only feature, one that isn't present in sh.